# Getting SCOPE_IDENTITY() after insert with select

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, scope-identity

Im having an issue getting the scope identity from an insert statement. I've done it numerous times before, but always with defined values:

```
INSERT INTO t_table (field1, Field2) 
VALUES (field1Val, field2Val); 
SET @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

How does one do so when you are getting the values for the insert by running a select from another table?

```
INSERT INTO t_table (field1, Field2) 
SELECT value1, value2 FROM #tempTable; 
SET @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

The above runs without error, but @id is null

Comment: To expand on Sean's answer: You can use an [`OUTPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause to get any data from the rows (Note plural.), e.g. identity column values for newly inserted rows.  `OUTPUT` can be used with `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `MERGE` and provides access to both before and after values in the case of `UPDATE`.  A tool well worth having in your pocket.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are trying to retrieve multiple values here you need to use the OUTPUT clause. It will return all the newly inserted values into a table or table variable.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx